# Send chat message

Tags: c#, windows-phone, win-universal-app, uwp

I have this code:

```
var msg = new ChatMessage();
msg.Body = "Test";
msg.Recipients.Add("number");

var cms = await ChatMessageManager.RequestStoreAsync();
await cms.SendMessageAsync(msg);
```

and I have a problem with the await part of code above. I get exception:

> Access is denied.

In capabilities within `appxmanifest` I have selected:

> Chat Message Access

(I tried select all, but It didn't work).
I cannot find any sample and requirements that must be met.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take a look [at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.chat.aspx) you will see that:

> This API is not available to all Windows/Windows Phone apps. Unless your developer account is specially provisioned by Microsoft, calls to these APIs will fail at runtime.

Comment: I found that I need restricted capabilities which are for Microsoft and their partners. ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt270968.aspx))