# Windows phone 8.1 app throws Access denied when using ChatMessageManager.RequestStoreAsync()

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I 'am developing windows phone 8.1 app. App has functionality that, it wants send sms in background without prompting composed window to user. Most of the example I came a cross are prompting compose window to user. Below is the code I try to use. But it throws

> access denied exception when executing
>   'ChatMessageStore cms = await ChatMessageManager.RequestStoreAsync()'.

```
ChatMessage msg = new ChatMessage();
msg.Body = "Test sms from windows phone";
msg.Recipients.Add("12345678");
ChatMessageStore cms = await ChatMessageManager.RequestStoreAsync();
await cms.SendMessageAsync(msg);
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Did you add the chat capability to your manifest? (I can't recall if this is Restricted or not).

Comment: I have tick all the options in capability tab in Package.appxmanifest file and try. But it not works.

Comment: According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt270968.aspx) it's not restricted. Are you calling `RequestAccess` from the UI or from the background? You can only call from the UI.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I think below is the line I have to add
<Capabilities>
 <uap:Capability Name="chat"/>
</Capabilities>
But Package.appxmanifest designer file do not have such a option call 'chat'. Other thing is I' am not using universal app. Its an windows phone 8.1 app. Do you have any code example?

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT According to [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.chat.aspx) it should be restricted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UWP - Send message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34276040/uwp-send-message)

Answer (score 0):

This [API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.applicationmodel.chat.chatmessagemanager.requestbecomingdefaultincomingtextmessagehandlerasync.aspx) is not available to all Windows/Windows Phone apps. Unless your developer account is specially provisioned by Microsoft, calls to these APIs will fail at runtime.

Comment: How can I get provisioned developer account ? Do you know way to create that kind of account. Is this developer account free? Is there any way to accomplish this without having that kind of developer account.

Comment: you can contact support team check here : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/c71422d1-7ec6-43f2-acd5-0cd689113b6c/use-chatmessagereader-in-windows-phone-81-c-winrt?forum=wpdevelop